# In HP-ALM, how do I find all open defects of "project=conversion"?

Tags: alm

I want to find

ALL OPEN (i.e, NOT(closed, Fixed, Pending Test Migration)) defects of Project = Conversion

Any tips? I realize HP ALM is very "niche"

Comment: Did the provided answer solve your problem, @Coffee? I'm looking at doing something similar, is this the level of complexity involved?

Comment: @PaulHicks -  hmm, this was a while ago and I flat - forgot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find it using the HP ALM GUI simply add a `Filter: Status[Open];Project["Conversion"]`.

If you want to find it using the HP ALM OTA API:

```
Set bugFactory = tdConnection.BugFactory
Set bugFilter = bugFactory.Filter
bugFilter.Filter("BG_STATUS") = "Open"
bugFilter.Filter("BG_PROJECT") = "Conversion"
Set bugs = bugFilter.NewList
```

See the HP ALM OTA API Reference (Objects BugFactory and TDFilter). See also the AP ALM Database Reference to get the right values to filter for (BG_STATUS and BG_PROJECT).